# running iphone application on iphone 4s for testing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

is it possible to run an iphone application on iphone 4s with the following settings:
1) base sdk (latest) IOS 4.3
2) Xcode version 4.1
3) Deployment target: 3.0

with these settings Xcode organizer cannot see my iphone (keeps loading ... but no device shown).

or should I upgrade to XCode 4.2.1 to get the job done ?

Comment: what is the os of the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not, Xcode shipped with the 4.3.2 SDK will not recognize the iPhone 4S and iOS 5.

You can however run an ad-hoc build on the iPhone 4S.

Comment: but how does an ad-hoc build will work with these same settings? and running the app will not work .. sounds weird !! right ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't. When running adhoc there is no XCode in the process.

Comment: Well you can create an ad-hoc build and install this build via iTunes. Just create the ipa and drag it in iTunes.